# How do I style only the last row of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can style a pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.diverging_palette(-5, 5, as_cmap=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4))
df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
```

[image: dataframe with styling applied to all rows]

but I can't figure out how to only apply a style to the last row. There is a `subset` option in the background_gradient call, and it suggests that I use an [index slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html) but I cannot figure out how to make just the last row have any kind of styling.

Here is my closest to success:

```py
df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=[2], axis='index')
```

[image: third column, not last row styled]

Comment: You want the last *row* correct? Not the last column?

Comment: Also, how do you want the colors to be defined? Should they still be scaled by the entire DataFrame, by row, or by column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the last element of your `index` as your subset.

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis=1, subset=df.index[-1])
```

---

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer to my question. Thanks, it also revealed that the error I was getting in my real (not toy) dataframe was coming from trying to apply this style to a column that had text, and not a number in it. So I actually need to apply it to last row, and everything but the first column.

Comment: If anyone else is looking for a way to apply this to multiple rows by index position, the syntax is `subset=pd.IndexSlice[[0, 2], :]`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `pd.IndexSlice` which is useful if you want to apply the style to multiple rows, including the last:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


cm = sns.diverging_palette(-5, 5, as_cmap=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4))

indices = pd.IndexSlice[[0, df.last_valid_index()], :]
df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis=1, subset=indices)
```

[image]