# Applying pandas styles to arbitrary (non-product) subsets of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, styles

How does one apply a style to an arbitrary subset of a pandas dataframe? Specifically, I have a dataframe `df` that contains some NaNs, and I want to apply a background gradient to it everywhere except where there are NaNs (with the same colormap applied to all cells).

I know that `background_gradient` (and `applymap` more generally) has a `subset` parameter, but I do not understand from the documentation how to use it to select an arbitrary subset of the dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [0, 1, np.nan], 'B': [.5, np.nan, 0], 'C': [np.nan, 1, 1]})
mask = ~pd.isnull(df)
```

Then if I try

```
df.style.background_gradient(subset=mask)
```

I get the error:

```
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I know how to apply a style to a subset of a dataframe in the specific case where that subset is a Cartesian product of indices and columns, using something like the solution here: [How do I style a subset of a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942827/how-do-i-style-a-subset-of-a-pandas-dataframe). So the question is what to do when the subset is not such a product, as in the example above.

One solution might be to loop through the columns and apply the style column-by-column (then each application *is* to a Cartesian product subset). In my case, I can pass `low` and `high` parameters to the `background_gradient` method to force the colormaps to match up between columns, but that fails when (as above) one or more of those columns contains a unique non-NaN value. This in turn could be bypassed by rewriting the `background_gradient` function, but that's clearly undesirable.

Comment: It looks there is an open [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21527) for this.

Comment: @rpanai I agree that if one could mask out NaNs in general from style functions, then that would do in my case. However it seems to me that there ought to be some way of applying styles to arbitrary subsets of dataframes, whether or not those subsets were defined by NaNs.

Comment: @rpanai: pandas [enhance #21527](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21527) was merged to [29118](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/29118) for a `highlight_null` back in 2019 / v0.17.1. I think this question is obsolete. OP can you rewrite, and state pandas version?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what version of pandas I was using at the time. But as I said in the comment above, my question was more general than ignoring NaNs in gradient fills (although that was the particular use case I had in mind at the time): it was about applying styles to arbitrary subsets of a dataframe, potentially indicated by a boolean mask. As far as I am aware, the best way to do that at present is using a custom function in conjunction with applymap, per Quang Hoang's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom function for this:

```
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
cmap = get_cmap('PuBu')

# update with low-high option
def threshold(x,low=0,high=1,mid=0.5):
    # nan cell
    if np.isnan(x): return ''

    # non-nan cell
    x = (x-low)/(high-low)
    background = f'background-color: rgba{cmap (x, bytes=True)}'
    text_color = f'color: white' if x > mid else ''
    return background+';'+text_color

# apply the style
df.style.applymap(threshold, low=-1, high=1, mid=0.3)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang, that works nicely. Seems odd to me that something like this isn't built in.